# Modifying the Codec List Object in an ASF file

Tags: video, codec, wmv, asf

Is it possible to modify the [Codec List Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370455(v=VS.85).aspx) in an ASF file? In particular, I would like to edit the codec name and description. I realize that this won't actually change the content of the video, but it's necessary for the video to be verified by an external tool.

Does anyone know of a tool that will allow me to do this? If not, does anyone have any suggestions about how I might go about doing it using the [Windows Media Format 11 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757738(VS.85).aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't likely possible to do it very easily. You try reverse engineering the format and working from there...but it will probably be more trouble than it's worth.